# How do I make a pop up in Tkinter when a button is clicked?

Tags: python, popup, tkinter

How do I make a pop-up in Tkinter when a button is clicked? When the 'About' button is clicked, I want a pop up with the disclaimer + about text.

I have tried to set up a def method but it must be very wrong because it's not working as I would like. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *

def clickAbout(): 
    name = ("Thanks for the click")
    return

app = Tk()
app.title("SPIES")
app.geometry("500x300+200+200")

labelText = StringVar()
labelText.set ("Please browse to the directory you wish to scan")


labelText2 = StringVar()
labelText2.set ("About \n \n \
SPIES will search your chosen directory for photographs containing \n \
GPS information. SPIES will then plot the co-ordinates on Google \n \
maps so you can see where each photograph was taken.")

labelText3 = StringVar()
labelText3.set ("\n Disclaimer \n \n \
Simon's Portable iPhone Exif-extraction Software (SPIES) \n \
software was made by Simon. This software \n \
comes with no guarantee. Use at your own risk")

label1 = Label(app, textvariable=labelText, height=0, width=100)
label1.pack()

label1 = Label(app, textvariable=labelText2, height=0, width=100)
label1.pack()

label = Label(app, textvariable=labelText3, height=0, width=100)
label.pack()

b = Button(app, text="Quit", width=20, command=app.destroy)
b.pack(side='bottom',padx=0,pady=0)

button1 = Button(app, text="About SPIES", width=20, command=clickAbout)
button1.pack(side='bottom',padx=5,pady=5)

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to display the text on a new window, then create a Toplevel widget and use it as the parent of the labels for the about text and the disclaimer.

By the way, Tkinter variables are not necessary if you have static text, so in this case you can simply get rid of them and replace them with multiline strings:

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *

ABOUT_TEXT = """About

SPIES will search your chosen directory for photographs containing
GPS information. SPIES will then plot the co-ordinates on Google
maps so you can see where each photograph was taken."""

DISCLAIMER = """
Disclaimer

Simon's Portable iPhone Exif-extraction Software (SPIES)
software was made by Simon. This software
comes with no guarantee. Use at your own risk"""

def clickAbout():
    toplevel = Toplevel()
    label1 = Label(toplevel, text=ABOUT_TEXT, height=0, width=100)
    label1.pack()
    label2 = Label(toplevel, text=DISCLAIMER, height=0, width=100)
    label2.pack()


app = Tk()
app.title("SPIES")
app.geometry("500x300+200+200")

label = Label(app, text="Please browse to the directory you wish to scan", height=0, width=100)
b = Button(app, text="Quit", width=20, command=app.destroy)
button1 = Button(app, text="About SPIES", width=20, command=clickAbout)
label.pack()
b.pack(side='bottom',padx=0,pady=0)
button1.pack(side='bottom',padx=5,pady=5)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a great help

Comment: @Bob: You may want to add a `toplevel.focus_force()` at the end of the `clickAbout()` function to activate the new window (which is how things like this work in most applications).

Comment: This is very helpful for me too. However `import sys` wasn't needed.