# tkinter on OSX: open new window instead of tab

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I want to open a new window in my tkinter app (python 3.6.5) on mac OSX (10.14). [Existing answers say to use TopLevel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261028/how-do-i-make-a-pop-up-in-tkinter-when-a-button-is-clicked). The following code works if System Preferences -> Dock -> "Prefer tabs when opening documents" is set to "In Full Screen Only". However, when that preference is set to "Always", the app preforms differently and opens TopLevel in a new tab, which is not my desired behavior (I'm actually looking for a blocking pop-up alert window regardless of the user's system preference).

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

ABOUT_TEXT = "I want this to open in a new window, not a tab"

def newWindow():
    toplevel = Toplevel(app)
    label1 = Label(toplevel, text=ABOUT_TEXT, height=0, width=100)
    label1.pack()


app = Tk()
app.title("tkinter: new window on mac")
app.geometry("500x300+200+200")


b = Button(app, text="Quit", width=20, command=app.destroy)
button1 = Button(app, text="Open new window", width=20, command=newWindow)
b.pack(side='bottom',padx=0,pady=0)
button1.pack(side='bottom',padx=5,pady=5)

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why but using root.resizable(False, False) to stop the window size being changed means a new window is created rather than a tab.